# File compiled by gcc on a musl toolchain not found by /bin/sh

Tags: gcc, musl

I was trying out the muslcc images on dockerhub, but cannot run a compiled Hello World program.

The image I am using is: muslcc/i686:x86_64-linux-musl (found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/muslcc/i686/tags)). I load the image with:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /path/to/local:/var muslcc/i686:x86_64-linux-musl
```

so that I can code on my local machine, and compile and test on the musl image.

---

The program I am compiling is a basic hello world:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    puts("Hello world.");
    return 0;
}
```

This file is saved as `helloworld.c`

I run `gcc -Wall helloworld.c` and get `a.out` in the same directory. Doing `ls -l` gives me:

```
total 1068
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7584 Jul 25 05:41 a.out
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            76 Jul 25 05:27 helloworld.c
```

When I try to run `a.out` with: `./a.out`, I get:

```
/bin/sh: ./a.out: not found
```

I have also tried to specific an output file, in case this is some problem with a default output, but no luck. I have also tried with an absolute path, a la `/var/a.out` but also, no luck.

--
Edits:

1. I have checked and the `./` symbol is in $PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it by adding the `-static` flag to gcc:

```
gcc -static input.c -o output.out
```